# Where the error in my actions?

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

I have one small task but I don't know where the error is in my actions. I'm using Yii2 2.0.10  with PostgreSQL and I need to update a few ActiveRecord models and change status in model. I wrote this code:

```
public function  actionActivate()
{
    $connection  = \Yii::$app->db;
    $ids=  implode(',',\Yii::$app->request->post('ids'));
    $whereCondition  = " id in ({$ids})";

    $result  = $connection->createCommand()
                          ->update('{{%user}}',['{{%user}}.status'=>USER::STATUS_ACTIVE],[$whereCondition])
                          ->execute();
    echo $result;
}
```

But when I try to execute the query I have this error:

```
>Exception &#039;yii\base\InvalidParamException&#039; with message &#039;Operator &#039; ID IN (1226,1227,1228,1229,1230,1231,1232,1233,1234,1235,1236,1237,1238,1239,1240,1241,1242,1243,1244,1245)&#039; requires two operands.&#039;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easier:

```
public function actionActivate()
{
    echo \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update(
        '{{%user}}', 
        ['status' => USER::STATUS_ACTIVE],
        ['id' => \Yii::$app->request->post('ids')]
    )->execute();
}
```